# Eclipse project with file resources that I'd like to write out on application start

Tags: java, eclipse, file, resources

I have an Eclipse plugin project that has several file resources that I would like to write out to disk (if they don't already exist) when the application starts up.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to essentially read the file as a resource and write it out using a FileWriter or some such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or do I have to essentially read the file as a resource and write it out using a FileWriter or some such

Pretty much, but the [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library has the [FileUtils.copyURLToFile()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29) method that makes this trivial.

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(MyClass.class.getResource("abc.txt"), new File("resources/abc.txt"));
```

Comment: not sure if eclipse dev kit has it's own filewriting tools, but if it doesn't the commons IO is a quick and easy way-- and Java's native `FileWriter` isn't that bad to use